# I need to consume data from a SharePoint 2010 through the REST site

Tags: ajax, rest, sharepoint-2010, xmlhttprequest, typescript1.5

I need to consume data from a SharePoint 2010 through the REST site.
I am calling through a ajax + Jquery request.
My host is localhost and I'm trying to call a host of other domain.

I'm trying to call a sharepoint list through a typescript project that is on my local machine

**I set the Cross-origin in my HEADER:**

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        url: path,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,

        success: function (response) { 
            if (response.d.__next) {
                recursive(response.d.__next);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        }
    });
```

**I set the Cross-origin in Source server WebConfig:**

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:50515" />
    <add name="X-MS-InvokeApp" value="1; RequireReadOnly" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, X-File-Name"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**But is taking place this error here:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:MyLocalHost/SiteOrigin/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/person?_=1457982013329. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401send @ jquery.min.js:4
```

controller.js:50 DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http:MyLocalHost/SiteOrigin/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/person?_=1457982013329.'.(…)
controller.js:51 error

*Already, thanks to everyone who can help me*

Answer (score 0):

This post is a year old so maybe the original poster gave up. Anyway You can use Nginx with a reverse proxy, eg:

```
location /sharepoint/ { proxy_pass   http://sharepoint/;}
```

And you can call your request this time to 'http://localhost/sharepoint/'. Last thing, it's very important to change in SharePoint Central Administration (Central Admin, Security and then Specify Authentication Providers) IIS7 Basic Auth enable. I hope this help somebody.